# Oracle OBIEE installation

Tags: oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I was trying to install OBIEE 11g Oracle Business Intelligence, on windows 8, but when my installation reached to step 13 of 14, *Deploying Financial Reporting JEE Application*, the installation failed!

Can anyone please tell me why this happened?

Thanks

Comment: Can u add exception photos i am not sure what is step 13 and 14.

Comment: You will find the photo of step 13 in this link thanks :
 
http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/201535/

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 is NOT a supported OS.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/documentation/fmw-122120-certmatrix-3254735.xlsx

Comment: what about windows 7 ?
formatting my computer and reinstall the operating system windows 7 , it will work ?? 
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Why not just look at the cert matrix yourself, instead of asking about Win7? But in general : OBIEE is a *server* product. Run it on a *server* OS, not a *desktop* one.

Comment: As Robin said: Server OS. Not desktop. The only Windows versions which are supported are 2012 and 2012R2.

Or just get VirtualBox and install into a Linux machine. Or even simpler download the fully packaged SampleApp VM: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Windows 10. I changed the compatibility settings (Right clicked the executable > Select Compatibility Tab > Choose windows 7 under "Select Compatibility Mode For") and the install went through successfully.